Can this Discrete Program Search have improved asymptotics in Haskell?
I've been researching how to use optimal evaluation to optimize Discrete Program Search and I arrived at a simple solution that seems to be really effective. Based on the following tests:
f 1001101110 = 1010100110
f 0100010100 = 1001101001

Solving for 'f' (by search), we find:
xor_xnor (0:0:xs) = 0 : 1 : xor_xnor xs
xor_xnor (0:1:xs) = 1 : 0 : xor_xnor xs
xor_xnor (1:0:xs) = 1 : 0 : xor_xnor xs
xor_xnor (1:1:xs) = 0 : 1 : xor_xnor xs

My best Haskell searcher, using the Omega Monad, takes 47m guesses, or about 2.8s. Meanwhile, the HVM searcher, using SUP Nodes, takes just 1.7m interactions, or about 0.0085s. More interestingly, it takes just 0.03 interactions per guess. This sounds like a huge speedup, so, it is very likely I'm doing something dumb. As such, I'd like to ask for validation.
I've published the Haskell code (and the full story, for these interested) below. My question is: Am I missing something? Is there some obvious way to optimize this Haskell search without changing the algorithm? Of course, the algorithm is still exponential and not necessarily useful, but I'm specifically interested in determining whether the optimal evaluation version is actually faster than what can be done in Haskell.
-- A demo, minimal Program Search in Haskell

-- Given a test (input/output) pairs, it will find a function that passes it.
-- This file is for demo purposes, so, it is restricted to just simple, single
-- pass recursive functions. The idea is to use HVM superpositions to try many
-- functions "at once". Obviously, Haskell does not have them, so, we just use
-- the Omega Monad to convert to a list of functions, and try each separately.

import Control.Monad (forM_)

-- PRELUDE
----------

newtype Omega a = Omega { runOmega :: [a] }

instance Functor Omega where
  fmap f (Omega xs) = Omega (map f xs)

instance Applicative Omega where
  pure x                = Omega [x]
  Omega fs <*> Omega xs = Omega [f x | f <- fs, x <- xs]

instance Monad Omega where
  Omega xs >>= f = Omega $ diagonal $ map (\x -> runOmega (f x)) xs

diagonal :: [[a]] -> [a]
diagonal xs = concat (stripe xs) where
  stripe []             = []
  stripe ([]     : xss) = stripe xss
  stripe ((x:xs) : xss) = [x] : zipCons xs (stripe xss)
  zipCons []     ys     = ys
  zipCons xs     []     = map (:[]) xs
  zipCons (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x:y) : zipCons xs ys

-- ENUMERATOR
-------------

-- A bit-string
data Bin
  = O Bin
  | I Bin
  | E

-- A simple DSL for `Bin -> Bin` terms
data Term
  = MkO Term      -- emits the bit 0
  | MkI Term      -- emits the bit 1
  | Mat Term Term -- pattern-matches on the argument
  | Rec           -- recurses on the argument
  | Ret           -- returns the argument
  | Sup Term Term -- a superposition of two functions

-- Checks if two Bins are equal
bin_eq :: Bin -> Bin -> Bool
bin_eq (O xs) (O ys) = bin_eq xs ys
bin_eq (I xs) (I ys) = bin_eq xs ys
bin_eq E      E      = True
bin_eq _      _      = False

-- Stringifies a Bin
bin_show :: Bin -> String
bin_show (O xs) = "O" ++ bin_show xs
bin_show (I xs) = "I" ++ bin_show xs
bin_show E      = "E"

-- Checks if two term are equal
term_eq :: Term -> Term -> Bool
term_eq (Mat l0 r0) (Mat l1 r1) = term_eq l0 l1 && term_eq r0 r1
term_eq (MkO t0)    (MkO t1)    = term_eq t0 t1
term_eq (MkI t0)    (MkI t1)    = term_eq t0 t1
term_eq Rec         Rec         = True
term_eq Ret         Ret         = True
term_eq _           _           = False

-- Stringifies a term
term_show :: Term -> String
term_show (MkO t)    = "(O " ++ term_show t ++ ")"
term_show (MkI t)    = "(I " ++ term_show t ++ ")"
term_show (Mat l r)  = "{O:" ++ term_show l ++ "|I:" ++ term_show r ++ "}"
term_show (Sup a b)  = "{" ++ term_show a ++ "|" ++ term_show b ++ "}"
term_show Rec        = "@"
term_show Ret        = "*"

-- Enumerates all terms
enum :: Bool -> Term
enum s = (if s then Sup Rec else id) $ Sup Ret $ Sup (intr s) (elim s) where
  intr s = Sup (MkO (enum s)) (MkI (enum s))
  elim s = Mat (enum True) (enum True)

-- Converts a Term into a native function
make :: Term -> (Bin -> Bin) -> Bin -> Bin
make Ret       _ x = x
make Rec       f x = f x
make (MkO trm) f x = O (make trm f x)
make (MkI trm) f x = I (make trm f x)
make (Mat l r) f x = case x of
  O xs -> make l f xs
  I xs -> make r f xs
  E    -> E

-- Finds a program that satisfies a test
search :: Int -> (Term -> Bool) -> [Term] -> IO ()
search n test (tm:tms) = do
  if test tm then
    putStrLn $ "FOUND " ++ term_show tm ++ " (after " ++ show n ++ " guesses)"
  else
    search (n+1) test tms

-- Collapses a superposed term to a list of terms, diagonalizing
collapse :: Term -> Omega Term
collapse (MkO t) = do
  t' <- collapse t
  return $ MkO t'
collapse (MkI t) = do
  t' <- collapse t
  return $ MkI t'
collapse (Mat l r) = do
  l' <- collapse l
  r' <- collapse r
  return $ Mat l' r'
collapse (Sup a b) =
  let a' = runOmega (collapse a) in
  let b' = runOmega (collapse b) in
  Omega (diagonal [a',b'])
collapse Rec = return Rec
collapse Ret = return Ret

-- Some test cases:
-- ----------------

test_not :: Term -> Bool
test_not tm = e0 && e1 where
  fn = make tm fn
  x0 = (O (I (O (O (O (I (O (O E))))))))
  y0 = (I (O (I (I (I (O (I (I E))))))))
  e0 = (bin_eq (fn x0) y0)
  x1 = (I (I (I (O (O (I (I (I E))))))))
  y1 = (O (O (O (I (I (O (O (O E))))))))
  e1 = (bin_eq (fn x1) y1)

test_inc :: Term -> Bool
test_inc tm = e0 && e1 where
  fn = make tm fn
  x0 = (O (I (O (O (O (I (O (O E))))))))
  y0 = (I (I (O (O (O (I (O (O E))))))))
  e0 = (bin_eq (fn x0) y0)
  x1 = (I (I (I (O (O (I (I (I E))))))))
  y1 = (O (O (O (I (O (I (I (I E))))))))
  e1 = (bin_eq (fn x1) y1)

test_mix :: Term -> Bool
test_mix tm = e0 && e1 where
  fn = make tm fn
  x0 = (O (I (O (O (O (I (O (O E))))))))
  y0 = (I (O (I (I (I (O (I (O (I (O (I (I (I (O (I (O E))))))))))))))))
  e0 = (bin_eq (fn x0) y0)
  x1 = (I (I (I (O (O (I (I (I E))))))))
  y1 = (I (I (I (I (I (I (I (O (I (O (I (I (I (I (I (I E))))))))))))))))
  e1 = (bin_eq (fn x1) y1)

test_xors :: Term -> Bool
test_xors tm = e0 && e1 where
  fn = make tm fn
  x0 = (I (I (O (O (O (I (O (O E))))))))
  y0 = (I (I (O (I E))))
  e0 = (bin_eq (fn x0) y0)
  x1 = (I (O (O (I (I (I (O (I E))))))))
  y1 = (O (O (I (O E))))
  e1 = (bin_eq (fn x1) y1)

test_xor_xnor :: Term -> Bool
test_xor_xnor tm = e0 && e1 where
  fn = make tm fn
  x0 = (I (O (O (I (I (O (I (I (I (O E))))))))))
  y0 = (I (O (I (O (I (O (O (I (I (O E))))))))))
  e0 = (bin_eq (fn x0) y0)
  x1 = (O (I (O (O (O (I (O (I (O (O E))))))))))
  y1 = (I (O (O (I (I (O (I (O (O (I E)))))))))) 
  e1 = (bin_eq (fn x1) y1)

main :: IO ()
main = search 0 test_xor_xnor $ runOmega $ collapse $ enum False


I think representing a bit string as a linked list means a lot of (bitwise) algorithms will run slowly, because for every bitwise operation, there are a lot of other instructions the CPU has to perform to move to the next items.

Fair enough, but note this is meant to represent the structure of an universal algorithm searcher. It just happens to use bit-strings, but generalizing it to more complex cases (like trees) would require all these instructions anyway. So it is interesting to investigate the algorithm under this presentation

At a guess: it should be possible to notice when a superposition need not be collapsed before determining that a term isn't right, letting you throw away entire branches of the search tree with just one "evaluation". It doesn't look like the current code does this -- though I guess there could easily be some subtleties I'm overlooking.

As a concrete example, all terms of shape Mat (MkO ...) ... are clearly not going to pass test_not. But I think you consider all of them individually anyway. If you were able to suspend the superpositions, and throw away Mat (MkO (Sup ... ...)) (Sup ... ...), instead, you'd be losing a huge chunk of the search space relatively cheaply.

(Aside: what is the distinction between an "interaction" and a "guess"? Is "interactions per guess" really a sensible unit?)

@DanielWagner yes I think some different way to arrange this to allow pruning these dead spaces would have the same asymptotics, but I don't know how that could be done without emulating SUP nodes (which would eventually become a slower reimplementation of the HVM?). Thinking about it

@DanielWagner interaction is the unit of work on HVM. It is equivalent to 1 beta-reduction (among other things). I use that metric just to illustrate there is an speedup / sharing effect. Otherwise, it would be impossible to call an entire recursive function with <1 beta-reductions. That's the point.

You say "pruning these dead spaces would have the same asymptotics". What are the two things that have the same asymptotics in this sentence? I guess at this point I've somewhat confused myself about exactly what you're asking -- perhaps in no small part because I'm not a domain expert, e.g. I have never heard of HVM or discrete program search before today. You may well be StackOverflow's #1 expert on those topics. There are some smart folks here, but you may need to guide us more carefully to what you need help with.

@DanielWagner By that sentence, I was just agreeing that, if we found a way to do what you suggested, then, I think the Haskell version could perform as well as the HVM approach. I apologize for assuming you'd know what HVM is. To be clear about what is being asked here, I'm precisely wondering whether we can make this specific Haskell program asymptotically faster, so that it doesn't take so long to run. Also asking if I'm doing something particularly slow. So it shouldn't need HVM expertise to answer, it is just mentioned for comparison.
